# Center a div larger than the browser window

Tags: html, css, center

So I made this div for a web projet, it's 1550px wide and I want it centered, no matter the browser's window size.

So far, with margin: 0 auto; I've managed to make it center when the browser windows it at least 1550px *

But when it's smaller, the div doesn't move anymore (it sticks to the left side)

```
<div class="mosaic rotate-left"></div>

.mosaic { text-align: center; 
position: relative; 
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1550px;
height: 1550px;
}
```

This is maybe a bit irrelevant but since it's another class in my div :

```
.rotate-left {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: exactly, if I correctly understand the meaning of viewport

Answer (score 1):

You can use the absolute/translate trick (it will be centered whatever the width):

```
.parent {
  position: relative; /* or absolute if you need */
}


.mosaic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This solution works until my browser is smaller than 1187px :) any idea ?

Comment: Can you link a fiddle ?

Comment: It seems to work for me http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/eNdRWL Edit: At least it is centered, but maybe you want it to be scrollable ?

Comment: its weird : for me, it stops working under 1200px :s

Comment: It is centered in mosaic-container (which is not centered in the viewport). If you want it to be centered in the viewport, you need to center the container  in the body as well (I updated the pen : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/eNdRWL ). Edit : What do you try to achieve exactly? Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Glad it helped ! Feel free to validate my answer  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
.mosaic{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-775px; /* half of the width */
    height:1550px;
}
```

just make sure the parent has a position:absolute/relative on it

Comment: adding these styles has just moved the div more to the left but i still encounter the same problem but thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

How about combining to two aslready working solutions?

```
@media (max-width: 1550px) {
  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 1550px;
    height: 1550px;
    left: 50%; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1549px) {
  .inner {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 1550px;
    height: 1550px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: this solution is incompatible with my project unfortunately :s thanks alot thought !

Comment: I doubt that, you will find a solution that works only with CSS and for all usefull browsers without media types. My Browser Firefox, shows the same behavior as you reported. Perhaps it's an error in the gecko engine. Did you try  Mehdi Brillaud's solution in a Chrome Browser? Is Javascript an option for you?